# can raster create multi-layer objects with different modes?

Tags: r, raster

Can a `raster` object (in R) have layers of different mode (data type)?

On the face of it it seems we are always forced to one type:

```
library(raster)
## create a SpatialPixelsDataFrame with (trivially) two different "layer" types
d <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 2:11), z = 1:100, a = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
coordinates(d) <- 1:2
gridded(d) <- TRUE

## now coerce this to a raster brick or stack and our "a" is crushed to numeric NA
all(is.na(getValues(brick(d)[[2]])))
[1] TRUE
```

Is there anything like a rasterDataFrame?

Also, note that we presumably cannot use R's factors since the raster@data is a matrix, or otherwise coerced to numeric/integer. Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 nice Q&A - handy for my work to know this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `raster` package provides the ability to create rasters with a categorical variable, and the `rasterVis` package includes functions for plotting them.  The `ratify` function allows a raster to include a lookup table relating the underlying raster integer values to other values, which can be character. This directly allows the use of any other mode of value in the levels part of the ratified raster.

Here's an example.

```
library(rasterVis)


r <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 1, ymn = 0, ymx = 2, nrow = 10, ncol = 11, 
            crs = as.character(NA))
r[] <- sample(seq_along(letters[1:5]), ncell(r), replace = TRUE)

## ratify the raster, and set up the lookup table
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$value <- letters[1:5]
rat$code <- 1:5

## workaround for limitation as at 2013-05-01
## see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-May/018180.html
rat$code <- NULL
levels(r) <- rat

levelplot(r)
```

There are coming updates to `rasterVis` that make the workaround above unnecessary.

Comment: Great. Thanks for posting both the question and this answer. This inspired me to go skim `raster`'s ChangeLog, and boy has there been a lot of work done on that already great package in the past year!

Comment: Ah gee, and thanks for fixing up my errors!  Shame on me for not checking the origin of ratify()

Comment: Just compiled a package from the most recent **rasterVis** source code on R-forge, and `levelplot`'s improved support for RAT's is pretty nifty. In the above code, you can drop `rat$code <- NULL`, and then run either `levelplot(r, att=1)` or `levelplot(r, att=2)` to plot with either `value` or `code` in the legend.