# Raster with integer value in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster

In part because I want to limit memory usage, I want to create a raster with integer values. I'm using the package raster in R. Although I appear to be able to create a raster with integer values, the extracted values are numeric. Here is a simple example.

```
library(raster)
# Create an empty raster
r <- raster(nrow=10,ncol=10)
# fill it with integer values
r[] <- 1:100
# It look like it's a integer raster
class(r[])
# but when you extract a value it's a numeric
class(r[1])
# if you extract it this way you get an integer
class(r[][1])
# But that's not always practical
```

Would someone be able to explain why this is the case and how I can get a raster that returns an integer value when I use `r[1]`?

I could not find anything regarding integer values, I found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290208/can-raster-create-multi-layer-objects-with-different-modes) that discuss categorical variables. But categorical variables take more memory than integer see:

```
object.size(r)
object.size(ratify(r))
```

Many thanks! Marie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* this is the case, but the general rule appears to be that **raster** will convert integer values to numeric values whenever the indices themselves are of class numeric. To ensure that the returned value isn't converted to  `"numeric"`, you'll need to take care to only use indices of class `"integer"`.

```
library(raster)
# Create an empty raster
r <- raster(nrow=10,ncol=10)
# fill it with integer values
r[] <- 1:100

class(1)
# [1] "numeric"
class(r[1])
# [1] "numeric"

class(1L)
# [1] "integer"
class(r[1L])
# [1] "integer"

class(1:2)
# [1] "integer"
class(r[1:2])
# [1] "integer"

class(1.7)
# [1] "numeric"
class(r[1.7])
# [1] "numeric"

class(r[as.integer(1.7)])
# [1] "integer"
class(r[as.integer(1.7)])
# [1] "integer"
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my original question very well. However, I'm now realizing that if you use [row,col], you'll get a numeric again. See: `class(r[1L,1L])`. Any reason why using the [row,col] indexing instead of [cell] indexing would results in different class? Is there a way to get an integer with [row,cell] indexing?

Comment: @MarieAuger-Methe -- Looks like you'll have to do something like `as.matrix(r)[1L,1L]` or `as(r[1,1], class(getValues(r, 1)))` to ensure that the results are  of the same type as the raster's elements. This becomes clear if you do `showMethods("[")` and then compare `getMethod("[", c("Raster", "numeric", "missing"))` and `getMethod("[", c("Raster", "numeric", "numeric"))`. The latter calls `cellFromRowColCombine()`, as in `cellFromRowColCombine(r,1L,1L)`,  which always returns an integer value; continuing on down the rabbit hole to `raster:::.doExtract()`, `.cellValues()`, `.readCells`

Comment: and onwards, you'll find that that initial conversion to `"numeric"` inevitably affects the returned result.

Comment: @JoshOBrien Thank you, I think I'll use `as.matrix(r)[1L,1L]`. I just made a quick test to see what was the most efficient method and I was surprise to see that `as.matrix(r)[1L,1L]` was faster than even `r[1L]`. See: `library(rbenchmark)` `benchmark(as.matrix(r)[2L,3L], r[cellFromRowColCombine(r,2L,3L)], as(r[2L,1L], class(getValues(r, 1))), r[13L], replications=1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use `getValues()`, which will return the correct class. In your case:

```
class(getValues(r))
```

Now to understand what is happening with `[]`, look at the source code in index.R:

1. `setMethod("[", c("Raster", "missing", "missing")` uses `getValues()` internally, which returns correct result.
2. `setMethod("[", c("Raster", "numeric", "missing"),`: uses `raster:::.doExtract` internally, which calls `raster:::.readCells()`. That last function contains a call to `cbind(uniquecells, vals)`, creating a matrix. A matrix in R can have only one type. Hence, even if *vals* is integer, *uniquecells* being numeric could make the whole numeric.

So when you used `r[]`, you were in case 1, while when you do `r[1]`, you are in case 2.